# Removing invalid UTF-8 from a multidimensional input array?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

The $_POST array can be multi-dimensional. I have code that removes invalid UTF, but also completely removes the sub arrays.

Running this code:

```
print_r($_POST);      
$UTF8_Input = array_map('_StripInvalidUTF8', $_POST);
print_r($UTF8_Input);

function _StripInvalidUTF8($str){
   return iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str);      
}
```

Produces:

```
//$_POST:
Array
(
    [Quantity] => 1
    [Options] => Array
        (
            [84] => 585
        )    
)


// $UTF8_Input:
Array
(
    [Quantity] => 1
    [Options] => 
)
```

The Options array is being truncated. Any suggestions on how to check the sub arrays for valid data and leave them intact if they are? I'm not sure exactly why they are being removed.

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
function _StripInvalidUTF8($str){
    if(is_array($str)) return array_map('_StripInvalidUTF8', $str);
        return iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str);      
}
```

Comment: I think a recursive function may be the answer, but this one isn't quite right. If `$str` is an array, it runs array_map, but doesn't store the result anywhere. It also tries to run iconv on `$str` even if `$str` is an array.

Comment: You need to add `return` before `array_map('_StripInvalidUTF8', $str);`. That way if it's an array it returns the result of `array_map` and if it's a string it returns the result of iconv.